# SQL Logic to merge two tables based on the given scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server

- Table 1 has Id with random date and the corresponding value.
- Table 2 has id with sequence date (it’s not necessarily to be sequence).

Matching  the Table2.Id and Table2.SequenceDate with Table1.Id and Table.RandomDate and then need to apply theTable1. value to the Table2 till the next Random Date occurs.

You can see in the below expected result

```
Table 1     
RandomDate   value   ID
2/12/2016        A    1
2/15/2016        B    1
2/18/2016        C    1
2/12/2016        A    2

Table 2     
SequenceDate    ID  
2/12/2016        1  
2/13/2016        1  
2/14/2016        1  
2/15/2016        1  
2/16/2016        1  
2/17/2016        1  
2/18/2016        1  
2/19/2016        1  
2/20/2016        1  
2/12/2016        2  


Expected Result from table and table 2      
SequenceDate    ID  value
2/12/2016        1  A
2/13/2016        1  A
2/14/2016        1  A
2/15/2016        1  B
2/16/2016        1  B
2/17/2016        1  B
2/18/2016        1  C
2/19/2016        1  C
2/20/2016        1  C
2/12/2016        2  A
```

Comment: What database platform?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got that logic, thanks everyone for all your inputs.

```
       SELECT 
        t2.Id,
        t2.SequenceDate,
        t1.RandomDate,
        t1.Value,
        ISNULL(LEAD(RandomDate,1,NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY Id  ORDER BY Id,RandomDate),DATEADD(YEAR,99,RandomDate)) AS nextRandomDte,
        ISNULL(LAG(RandomDate,1,NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY Id  ORDER BY Id,RandomDate),RandomDate) AS prevRandomDte
    FROM 
          dbo.table1 t1
    RIGHT JOIN dbo.table2 t2 
           ON t1.Id = t2.Id
             AND ( t2.SequenceDate >= t2.RandomDate OR 
                     t2.RandomDate = prevRandomDte
                   )
             AND t2.SequenceDate <  nextRandomDte
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a subquery to get the expected value.

```
    select
        Table2.SequenceDate,
        Table2.ID,
        (   select top 1 Table1.Value
            from Table1
            where Table1.RandomDate <= Table2.SequenceDate
            and Table1.ID = Table2.ID
            order by Table1.RandomDate desc
        ) as Value
    from Table2
```

Comment: Here the sub query acting as independent set and there is no join predicate on the id. So its producing wrong result.

Comment: @user3600663 You're right. I corrected the query, and also named the third column 'Value' as you had in the question

Answer (score 0):

This is one way

**[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9abef/41)**

```
SELECT *
FROM Table2 t2
JOIN Table1 t1
  ON t2.[ID] = t1.[ID]
 AND t1.[RandomDate] = (SELECT MAX(t3.[RandomDate]) 
                        FROM Table1 t3 
                        WHERE t3.[RandomDate] <= t2.[SequenceDate])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| SequenceDate | ID |  RandomDate | value | ID |
|--------------|----|-------------|-------|----|
|  12 Feb 2016 |  1 | 12 Feb 2016 |     A |  1 |
|  13 Feb 2016 |  1 | 12 Feb 2016 |     A |  1 |
|  14 Feb 2016 |  1 | 12 Feb 2016 |     A |  1 |
|  15 Feb 2016 |  1 | 15 Feb 2016 |     B |  1 |
|  16 Feb 2016 |  1 | 15 Feb 2016 |     B |  1 |
|  17 Feb 2016 |  1 | 15 Feb 2016 |     B |  1 |
|  18 Feb 2016 |  1 | 18 Feb 2016 |     C |  1 |
|  19 Feb 2016 |  1 | 18 Feb 2016 |     C |  1 |
|  20 Feb 2016 |  1 | 18 Feb 2016 |     C |  1 |
|  12 Feb 2016 |  2 | 12 Feb 2016 |     A |  2 |
```

**Second Version:** With this way you create the ranges first and then see on which range belong the sequence.

```
WITH Ranges as (
    SELECT  [ID],
            [RandomDate] [start], 
            LEAD([RandomDate],1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID]
                                             ORDER BY [RandomDate]) [end],
            [value]
    FROM Table1
) 
SELECT t2.[ID], 
       t2.[SequenceDate],
       r.*
FROM Table2 t2
JOIN Ranges r
  ON  t2.[ID] = r.[ID]
 AND  t2.[SequenceDate] >= r.[start]
 AND (t2.[SequenceDate] < r.[end] OR r.[end] IS NULL)
ORDER BY 1,2
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID |             | ID |       start |         end | value |
|----|-------------|----|-------------|-------------|-------|
|  1 | 12 Feb 2016 |  1 | 12 Feb 2016 | 15 Feb 2016 |     A |
|  1 | 13 Feb 2016 |  1 | 12 Feb 2016 | 15 Feb 2016 |     A |
|  1 | 14 Feb 2016 |  1 | 12 Feb 2016 | 15 Feb 2016 |     A |
|  1 | 15 Feb 2016 |  1 | 15 Feb 2016 | 18 Feb 2016 |     B |
|  1 | 16 Feb 2016 |  1 | 15 Feb 2016 | 18 Feb 2016 |     B |
|  1 | 17 Feb 2016 |  1 | 15 Feb 2016 | 18 Feb 2016 |     B |
|  1 | 18 Feb 2016 |  1 | 18 Feb 2016 |      (null) |     C |
|  1 | 19 Feb 2016 |  1 | 18 Feb 2016 |      (null) |     C |
|  1 | 20 Feb 2016 |  1 | 18 Feb 2016 |      (null) |     C |
|  2 | 12 Feb 2016 |  2 | 12 Feb 2016 |      (null) |     A |
```

Comment: Note this takes 2 joins instead of 1, and there's a way to do it with 1, which may perform better.

Comment: @ErikE Yes, I say. `This is one way`. Im trying to do it with `LEAD()`

Comment: @ErikE But if you have a fastest way should post it. Not sure if `LEAD()` will use a single `JOIN` yet

Comment: Okay, posted. Not sure if it will be faster. It might.

Comment: For the above sample table it might work but if added some values on table 1 then its creating the problem . If you add some more values on Table 1 with different id with different value like x,y,z, then you will see the difference, because in the sub query we're picking just the max date with no join condition

Comment: Just read about the lead() .. hope that should work.. thanks for all your inputs

Comment: @user3600663 Update my sqlFiddle demo with the new data, press RUN and share the link. Or update the question so we can test that case.

Comment: posted my answer, please check it out

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   t2.SequenceDate,
   t2.Id,
   t1.Value
FROM
   dbo.Table2 t2
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 t1.*
      FROM dbo.Table1 t1
      WHERE
         t1.Id = t2.Id
         AND t1.RandomDate <= t2.SequenceDate
      ORDER BY
         t1.RandomDate DESC
   ) t1
;
```

You definitely need an appropriate index on Table2, such as `(Id, RandomDate)`.

The `OUTER APPLY` instead of `CROSS APPLY` is so that a `NULL` will be shown for `Value` if no matching date is found.